# Compiling .NET Managed Code as a Native Win32 App

Tags: compiler-construction, clr, native, converters

i write an app in .NET 4.0, then i compile it, CLR code is generated,

what i am looking for is , fingers crossed, some compiler which compiles my .NET Code and makes a Native Win32 App or which takes my compiled CLR and converts it to a native Win32 App.

are there any such compilers or converters out there. If yes then please tell me.

by now some genius has to have such compiler or converter, ofcourse such a utility will have to pick up and statically link the managed libraries.

p.s i need a Windows Based Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any .NET code needs a .NET runtime.

I played around with the trial version of [.NET Linker](http://www.rustemsoft.com/net_link_dll.htm), which can link the .NET runtime into your executable / DLL so that there is no external dependency on .NET.  I never tried it in a production environment.

Presumably if you expose your classes e.g. using COM (COM visible), the final result could be consumed in that manner.

Comment: Consumed means used by.  If some of your .NET classes expose a COM interface, that COM interface should be available after .NET Linker runs (I did not test that though).